# How to display images on Pebble watch

Tags: object, xcode6, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am new to pebble development. I want to show Image as a notification in pebble watch according to some conditions.

I searched the web but doesn't found anything use full.

Any one knows how can I do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to implement?